# Generate pdf from OpenApi in spring boot maven project

Tags: spring-boot, maven-3, springdoc-openapi-ui, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

I would like to know, is there a way to generate a pdf docuementation from OpenApi 3, using maven plugins.
For intance in swagger, it was possible using :

- swagger-maven-plugin : -> swagger.json file
- swagger2markup-maven-plugin : swagger.json file ->  Asciidoc
- asciidoctor-maven-plugin : Asciidoc -> pdf

Thank you

Comment: You already mentioned it via `asciidoctor-maven-plugin..

Comment: no it's not possible in open api 3